# I don't have the render, dimensions tabs in the scene panel

Tags: rendering, animation, blender-internal-render-engine

I don't have the render, dimensions tabs in the scene panel.

How I reset it ?

[image]

Comment: What render engine do you have selected? That looks like the game engine settings and not cycles or internal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are currently in Blender's Game Engine. You need to switch it to either Blender Internal or Cycles. I recommend Cycles because of it's realistic lighting. [image]

Comment: ooooooooooooooh ok thank you for your answer :)